# slidetoggle() with UL LI

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

Please find the below html and the related code

```
<div class="lang">
            <a href="Text A url" class="uk lclick">Text A</a>
        </div>
        <div id="lang_menu" class="small_menu">
            <ul class="lang-list">
                <li><a href="Text B url" class="de">Text B</a></li>
                <li class="no-sep"><a href="Text C url" class="tr">Text C</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="small_menu_bottom">
            </div>
        </div>
​
```

1. The user clicks on the div 'lang' which has an anchor tag 'Text A' ,
   clicking on this anchor tag the user will be re-directed to a particular page.
2. when the user clicks on the 'lang' div  the slideToggle() function is
   executed and the div 'langmenu' is shown to the user. (this gives a dropdown effect)
3. This 'langmenu' div has two more anchor tags (Text B and Text C) Please
   find the above html code.
4. When the user clicks on either of the anchor tags the page is redirected to the respective urls as per href   property of anchor tag.
5. The problem is irrespective of what anchor tag user selects i.e.,'Text B' or 'Text c' , after the page redirects only 'Text A' is displayed in the dropdown. where as the selected anchor tag text should be displayed

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Please find the jquery and css .

```
.lang{background:url(someurl) no-repeat; display:block; padding:0 9px; width:145px;height:22px; cursor:pointer; position:absolute; top:24px; left:188px;}

.lang-list li a.uk{ background:url(someurl) left center no-repeat;}
.lang-list li a.de{ background:url(someurl) left center no-repeat;}
.lang-list li a.tr{ background:url(someurl) left center no-repeat;}

#lang_menu{position:absolute; top:48px; left:188px; width:159px;display:none; cursor:pointer; z-index:100;}

.small_menu, .small_menu_bottom{background:url(someurl) 0 0 no-repeat; width:159px;}
.small_menu_bottom{clear:both; background-position:-161px 0; height:10px; display:block; margin-bottom:-10px;}

.lang-list li{height:25px; line-height:25px; background:url(someurl) center bottom repeat-x; margin:0 1px;padding-left:15px;}

li.no-sep{ background:none;height:15px; line-height:15px; padding-top:8px;}
```

I dont use jquery very often , so I am finding it difficult to resolve this issue. It may be a simple fix , please let me know .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lang').click(function () {
        $("#lang_menu").slideToggle();
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

> $(document).ready(function () {
>       $('.lang > a').click(function () {
>           $("#lang_menu").slideToggle();
>       }); });​

As of your code, the #lang_menu is part of the click listener.. if it is nested

Comment: The above code is not working becasue , I need the whole div 'lang' clickable, only making the anchor tag clickable does not serve the purpose.

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do a bit more clear ... hard to understand what you want. Rephrase your question...

Comment: I have re-framed my question, can you please have a look

Comment: Sorry still don't get it. You need to say, this is what the user does, then this should happen. what is the problem right now? Reformat your code as well, your references to the code in text should be clear, anchor tag ? You have no anchor links ... sorry... make your example more clear. The easier it is, the more likely you will get help.

Comment: re-framed again. Please check